# Do I include Front-end (HTML/Javascript) as a separate Microservice

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I will be using Angular and Spring Bootstrap in a microservice architecture:

1) Do I place the Angular module as its own microservice?

2) If the first question is true, do all front-end microservices run on the same AWS instance or separately?

Comment: Hi, does any answer fits your needs? If so, do you mind accepting the "answer"? This will help us and future visitors. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235. If not, let us know what's missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer(s)

> 1) Do I place the Angular module as its own microservice?

***Yes***, if the Angular module is composed of "static" content and/or does not require an application server. By "static" I mean, for example, pure HTML/javascript and not a single AJAX/SOAP/REST calls to another service or a backend.

***Yes***, if the angular app is a lightweight independently-deployable web application (HTML+JS+WebServices).

***No***, if you decide "to turn" the Angular+SpringBoot combo into a microservice instead. Cf. explanations below.

> 2) If the first question is true, do all front-end microservices run
>   on the same AWS instance or separately?

***It depends***. Cf. explanations below.

---

### Why

I believe its important to recall what really characterizes a microservice in a microservices architecture. To that purpose I will quote some interesting parts (among others) from Wikipedia:

- Services in a microservice architecture are independently deployable
- Services are organized around business capabilities
- A microservice is not a layer within a monolithic application. Rather it is a **self-contained piece of business functionality** with clear interfaces, and may, through its own internal components, implement a layered architecture
- Main benefits are: modularity, scalability (especially horizontal), integration and delivery (CI, CD)

So it is not the technology (Angular, Spring Boot) nor the layer (backend, frontend) that will strictly define a microservice.

---

**Instead you have to ask yourself:**

1. What level of granularity you want to achieve
2. What do I want to make independently deployable (or containerizable)
3. How do I plan to scale?
4. How do I want to deliver updates?

   *(non-exhaustive list...)*

And in the end, you may come up with at least two possibilities:

- **(1)** Say your whole Angular + Spring Boot (app) form a microservice independently deployable so that it could be containerized and ran on multiple AWS instances behind i.e. a load balancer, eventually taking benefits from clustering capabilities.
- **(2)** Say your Angular app (JS) and its services (i.e. REST) form a microservice that you can deploy on any Web/Application server along with other microservices.

Case **(1)** could resemble:

```
AWS Instance1
  Docker container
     SpringBoot + Angular app (JS+WS)
AWS Instance2
  Docker container
     SpringBoot + Angular app (JS+WS)
```

while case **(2)** would resemble:

```
AWS Instance1
  SpringBoot
    Angular app1 (JS+WS)
    Angular app2 (JS+WS)
AWS Instance2
  SpringBoot
    Angular app1 (JS+WS)
    Angular app2 (JS+WS)
```

In the latest example, I put two similar microservices alongside (app1 and app2) to illustrate coexisting independently deployable business units.

Other combinations of technologies (with actual dependencies also!) are possible. An example:

```
AWS.Instance1 (Front-End)
   ApplicationServer
     MicroService1 (facing REST-API)
     MicroService2 (AngularJS app + REST)
AWS.Instance2 (Back-end)
   ApplicationServer
     MicroService3 (business/core REST-API)
     ...
```

Here the front-end (MS2) uses a REST facade (MS1) that may call back-end functions (MS3). It is easy to update each component separately and to scale you would have to create two new AWS instances with a similar layout. Just a taste...

You will notice that independently-deployable does not mean any dependency at all. There will (and often) exist logical/functional dependencies between (micro)services, so the keyword here is independently-**deployable**.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I place the Angular module as its own microservice?

Your Angular module is front-end which requires a separate application server `node` so you need to run it separately.

> If the first question is true, do all front-end microservices run on
>   the same AWS instance or separately?

For both services(angular + spring-boot), you need different application servers not different instances so you can deploy both the services over a single AWS instance which listens to the different ports.

e.g. angular-app on 3000 and spring-boot on 8080 (it's your choice)

I hope this info is fulfilled your need.